# Change Actual Approver value of an approval process from apex

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, approval-process, approval-history

I have Visualforce page hosted on the force.com site. The user (or an approver) can approve/reject the request of certain custom object records using this page. The page shows him a comment box and two buttons (one for approval and one for rejection).

I am performing the approval and rejection actions in the apex controller using ProcessWorkitemRequest. So something like this:

```
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
req.setComments(approvalRequestComments);
req.setAction('Approve');
Id workItemId = getWorkItemId(recordId); 

if(workItemId == null){
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Work item id not found'));
} else {
    req.setWorkitemId(workItemId);
    // Submit the request for approval
    Approval.ProcessResult result =  Approval.process(req);
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'You have successfully approved this request.'));
}

public Id getWorkItemId(Id targetObjectId) {
    Id retVal = null;
    for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem workItem  : [Select p.Id from ProcessInstanceWorkitem p where p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId =: targetObjectId]) {
        retVal  =  workItem.Id;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Everything works fine, except when we open the record in salesforce, in the approval history section, the **Actual Approver** column shows **Site Guest User** instead of the User to which this request was assigned to.

So, is there a way to manipulate the Actual Approver value from the apex controller? I tried setting the next approver id but it still shows the Site Guest User.

Comment: Running an `Approval Process` through a `Site`? That has bad idea written all over it.