# How to change Actual Approver value of an approval process from Apex

Tags: apex, approval-process, approval-history

source：[change-actual-approver-value-of-an-approval-process-from-apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139017/change-actual-approver-value-of-an-approval-process-from-apex)

2

I have Visualforce page hosted on the force.com site. The user (or an approver) can approve/reject the request of certain custom object records using this page. The page shows him a comment box and two buttons (one for approval and one for rejection).

I am performing the approval and rejection actions in the apex controller using `ProcessWorkitemRequest`. So something like this:

```
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
req.setComments(approvalRequestComments);
req.setAction('Approve');
Id workItemId = getWorkItemId(recordId); 

if(workItemId == null){
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Work item id not found'));
} else {
    req.setWorkitemId(workItemId);
    // Submit the request for approval
    Approval.ProcessResult result =  Approval.process(req);
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'You have successfully approved this request.'));
}

public Id getWorkItemId(Id targetObjectId) {
    Id retVal = null;
    for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem workItem  : [Select p.Id from ProcessInstanceWorkitem p where p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId =: targetObjectId]) {
        retVal  =  workItem.Id;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Everything works fine, except when we open the record in salesforce, in the approval history section, the Actual Approver column shows Site Guest User instead of the User to which this request was assigned to.

So, is there a way to manipulate the Actual Approver value from the apex controller? I tried setting the next approver id but it still shows the Site Guest User.

Comment: same question：https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AaWXIA0